# Create simple trigger for some minutes

Tags: android

in android service i have some automatics request from server, for example each 3 minute get latest news and each 10 minutes latest comments. i wrote this simple code to trigger them, but i think thats not useful and maybe my `webservice` cant work correctly by this method

Service:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    int    second       = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60;

    if (second == G.receive_latest_news) {
       G.SYSTEM_MILISECOND = second;
       G.receive_latest_news = second + (180 * 60);
       get_latest_news();
    }

    if (second == G.receive_latest_news) {
       G.SYSTEM_MILISECOND = second;
       G.receive_latest_comments = second + (600 * 60);
       get_latest_comments();
    }
}
```

`G` class as `Application` (defined on manifest):

```
public class G extends Application {
    public static  int  SYSTEM_MILISECOND = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60;

    public static  int  receive_latest_news;
    public static  int  receive_latest_comments;
}
```

`Alarm Manager` to trigger service

```
public class BroadcastConfiguration extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static void setAlarmSate(Context context, boolean start) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ServiceEitaaUpdater.class);
        intent.setAction("sample.alarms.receive_data");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, RequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        if (IS_CONNECTION)
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + START_PERIOD, G.getScheduleRepeatPeriod(), pendingIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `setAlarmSate()` method, you use this code to set alarm:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + START_PERIOD, G.getScheduleRepeatPeriod(), pendingIntent);
```

If you want to use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` type, you should use the time return by `System.currentTimeMillis()` method. You can see more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: yes sure, but i dont have problem with that, is correct me method to trigger service each 3 and 10 minute?